# Bet365 how to have some data?

Tags: python, web-scraping

hope this one will be the last question here.

I'm trying to take some data from https://www.bet365.it/#/AS/B1/

In particular I want to have a data frame with all the matches (only home team and away team) listed for the current day under the cluster "competition" and consequently from all the leagues from each nation. It means that this code must enter in each league, take the data, come back to the previous page and go to the next league.

I haven't found the API and googling around i don't even think is available

Can someone help me?

C

Comment: it may use private API (you would have to check all requests from browser to server) which you may try to use but you can't get documentation and it may block you. I can't check it because it shows me `"Our location services have detected you are in a country that bet365 does not offer its services to."`

Comment: Ok thanks, any other tips?

Comment: I saw few question about `home team and away team` on different pages and they need different solutions. First check if page runs without JavaScript - you can turn off JavaScript in browser and open page. If it needs JavaScript then you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.